# how to manuplate the google api php client

Tags: php, api, google-api, google-api-php-client

how to manuplate this code to get the details of book by passing the isbn number of the book

```
$client = new \Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName("BestBook");
$client->setAuthConfigFile('temp.json');
$client->addScope(\Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE);
$client->setDeveloperKey("AIzaSyD6OrKhhJiseBimFVJZ_7OV5tyPdg4LxZiY");

$service = new \Google_Service_Books($client);
$results = $service->volumes->listVolumes('Henry David Thoreau');

foreach ($results as $item) {
  echo $item['volumeInfo']['imageLinks']['smallThumbnail'], "<br /> \n";
}
```

And any idea why it is showing 10 output when i pass one isbn

Comment: what happends if you change 'Henry David Thoreau' to the isbn number?

Comment: it works but i dnt why it shows 10 result, like 10 images

Comment: ** Keep your API key private. If someone obtains your key, they could use it to consume your quota or incur charges against your Google API Console project.

Comment: yaa thanks bro i have now generated a new one

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? Same issue here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please consider the fact that Google Books provide you ISBN_13 and ISBN_10. Having that in mind you need to do the following:

```
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName("BestBook");
$client->setDeveloperKey("asdfkjeriuIEWURkjfaskd");

$optParams = array(
    'filter' => 'ebooks'//,
    //'langRestrict' => 'es',
    //'orderBy' => 'relevance'
 );

$isbnNumber = 9781452052656;
$results = $service->volumes->listVolumes($isbnNumber, $optParams);

// HANDLE RESULT
foreach ($results as $item) {     

    if ($item['volumeInfo']['industryIdentifiers'][0]['identifier'] == $isbnNumber ) { // For ISBN_13 (for ISBN_10 use $item['volumeInfo']['industryIdentifiers'][1]['identifier'] )

    echo " - ".utf8_decode($item['volumeInfo']['title']), "<br />";

    } 
}
```

By the way, since you are not accessing user data but instead just application data then you don't need to use the lines `$client->addScope(\Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE);` and `$client->setAuthConfigFile('temp.json');`

Oh! I almost forgot! Please do not post your API Key here because that is sensitive information!

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it show many error like undefined variable $optparams and i have jst started to work with api so i dnt knw perfect way and i hav passed config setting in temp.json, if i dnt use that then will i pass my api keys??

Comment: sry it only shows this error 
cURL error 7: (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)

Comment: If you are starting with this stuff, I strongly suggest following the instructions here https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/start/get_started. It should help you to understand how this works.